# How to take output of MySQL SHELL utility in file

Tags: javascript, mysql, database-administration

I am running `util.checkForServerUpgrade()` function in JS mode in MySQL Shell utility. **I need output of mentioned function in file instead of command-line.**

Here is the exact syntax which I am using:

```
util.checkForServerUpgrade('root@localhost:3306', {"password":"abc", "targetVersion":"8.0.11", "outputFormat":"JSON", "configPath":"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini"})
```

I have tried appending `> output.json` and many more but not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the util.checkForServerUpgrade call from the command line when mysqlsh ist started:

```
mysqlsh root:****@localhost:3306 -e "util.checkForServerUpgrade('root@localhost:3306', {\"password\":\"abc\", \"targetVersion\":\"8.0.11\", \"outputFormat\":\"JSON\", \"configPath\":\"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini\"})" > err.log
```